# app_browser deployment

Tags: asp.net

I have written a PageAdapter that handles viewstate persistence in a SQL server. This page adapter was created in it's own project so that i can reuse the DLL on other projects.

I have another project that is acting as my test web application. I added an entry the configuration file for the new database connection string. I also had to create a browser file in the app_browser folder. I will tell you upfront that I am not familiar with the app_browser and browser files at all. So this is probably a setup issue.

I have this solution working properly on development. I then tried to deploy my project using a web deployment project to compile the application, and then manually move the output to the test server. On the test server, it acts like it is not reading the app_browser folder. My code never gets executed. I started up a remote debugging session and my code never fired. All of the necessary files are there.

The server is windows server 2003 standard edition with SP 2. It is 32-bit. It is running IIS 6.0. We have all of the .Net frameworks installed. IIS is currently configured to run framework 4.0. My code is using 2.0.

I am not finding a whole lot of information online about it, but I know I can't be the first to have this issue. Please someone help me out here.

Below is the contents of my browser file.

```
<browsers>
  <browser refID="Default">
  <controlAdapters>
    <adapter controlType="System.Web.UI.Page" adapterType="BEKCustomViewState.BEKViewStatePageAdapter"/>
  </controlAdapters>
  </browser>
</browsers>
```

Comment: Did you GAC the assembly for the PageAdapter on the server?

Comment: No, but it is included in the bin folder with the debug file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, this doesn't explain what caused the issue, but it is definitely a viable workaround. I will probably implement this in my deployment project so that I don't have to worry about it.

http://conficient.wordpress.com/2010/05/11/fix-for-precompiled-websites-from-vs2010-on-net-3-5-for-cssfriendly-adapters/